# The expressions which evaluate to a boolean value can not be concatenated with a String in Java. Why?

Tags: java

Let's see the following simplest code snippet in Java.

```
final public class Parsing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int p=10;
        int q=10;

        System.out.println(p==q);
    }
}
```

---

The above code in Java is fine and displays **true** as both p and q of the same type (int) contain the same value (10). Now, I want to concatenate the argument of println() so that it contains a new line escape sequence **\n** and the result is displayed in a new line as below.

```
System.out.println("\n"+p==q);
```

Which is not allowed at all because the expression **p==q** evaluates a boolean value and  a boolean type in Java (not Boolean, a wrapper type) can never be converted to any other types available in Java. Therefore, the above mentioned statement is invalid and it issues a compile-time error. What is the way to get around such situations in Java?

---

and surprisingly, the following statements are perfectly valid in Java.

```
System.out.println("\n"+true);
System.out.println("\n"+false);
```

and displays true and false respectively. How? Why is the same thing in the statement `System.out.println("\n"+p==q);` not allowed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to add parentheses () around p==q (the way you write it, it will be interpreted as ("\n"+p) == q, and String cannot be compared to a boolean). This operator precedence is desired for expressions like

```
if(a+b == c+d)
```

etc. So,

```
System.out.println("\n"+(p==q));
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: This may be helpful [operator precedence](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 2):

The order of precedence of operators means that your expression gets evaluated as

```
 ("\n" + p) == q
```

It is nonsensical to compare a string to an int so compilation fails, try:

```
 "\n" + (p == q)
```

Answer (score 2):

> System.out.println("\n"+p==q);

compiler treat it as

```
System.out.println(("\n"+p)==q);
```

Use

```
System.out.println("\n"+(p==q));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Which is not allowed at all because the expression p==q evaluates a boolean value and a boolean type in Java (not Boolean, a wrapper type) can never be converted to any other types available in Java.

This is completely wrong. Concatenating anything to a String is implemented by the compiler via `String.valueOf()`, which is also overloaded to accept booleans.

The reason for the compiler error is simply that `+` has a higher operator precedence than `==`, so your code is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(("\n"+p)==q);
```

and the error occurs because you have a `String` and an `int` being compared with `==`

On the other hand, this works just as intended:

```
System.out.println("\n"+(p==q));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah. The statement is wrong.

```
System.out.println("\n"+(p==q));
```

~Dheeraj